# UAC consent.exe doesn't render when remoting

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, uac

Im using remoted desktop to access a Win7 machine.  when I ctrl+shift click an icon or right click to run it as administrator nothing happens.  I see that a new instance of consent.exe is added to the processes in windows task manager but nothing is rendered to approve the execution.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem all the time when remoting into a Vista box and would have to slowly Alt-Tab through all the running applications to get the UAC dialog to finally popup.  I haven't had that problem yet with 7 thankfully.  I can only figure there's something that's causing it to start in a "minimized" state of some sort.

Comment: It's not about it being minimised, per se, but losing focus because of the remoting session. I've given you a +1 for this answer though, because it's how I do it.